# Transfer file over Bluetooth to smartphone and received information for loss/re-transmit packets

Tags: bluetooth

I'm interested in monitoring lost/re-transmitted/other data for transferring files from PC to Smartphone.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Smartphone: xiaomi pocophone f1

I know how to transfer files(using Blueman), but what I really need is a software of some sort, something like `hcitool` which might help in sending data + **detecting packets loss/re-transmission**.

Any software that might help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data I simply used Blueman on Ubuntu.
Then, from WireShark I sniff the bluetooth0 interface, with filter `btl2cap.retransmittimeout`.
To automate that I wrote a Python script that uses `pyshark`.

```
import pyshark

class SniffPacket(object):
    def sniff(self):
        capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='bluetooth0', display_filter='btl2cap.retransmittimeout')
        try:
            capture.sniff(timeout=20)
        except:
            pass
        return capture

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Initiate sniffer...')
    capture = SniffPacket().sniff()
    print('Sniffer complete, parse data...')
    ct = 0
    try:
        while True:
            res = str(capture.next_packet())
            ct += 1
    except:
        pass
    print('Retransmitted packets: ' + str(ct))
```